# C# wrting/burning large wav file on Audio CD

Tags: c#, istream, cd-burning

I used this article to write Audio CD

[Creating Audio CDs using IMAPI2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/audio_cd.aspx)

Following this article i can write Audio CD, but with smaller wav files (upto 30 min audio file)

And OutOfMemoryException is thrown on line

IntPtr fileData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((IntPtr)SizeOnDisc);

```
public void PrepareStream()
{
byte[] waveData = new byte[SizeOnDisc];

//
// The size of the stream must be a multiple of the sector size 2352
// SizeOnDisc rounds up to the next sector size
//
IntPtr fileData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((IntPtr)SizeOnDisc);
FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath);

int sizeOfHeader = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WAV_HEADER));

//
// Skip over the Wav header data, because it only needs the actual data
//
fileStream.Read(waveData, sizeOfHeader, (int)m_fileLength - sizeOfHeader);

Marshal.Copy(waveData, 0, fileData, (int)m_fileLength - sizeOfHeader);

CreateStreamOnHGlobal(fileData, true, out wavStream);
}
```

I tried to create IStream some other ways but IMAPI2 API gives following error
E_IMAPI_DF2RAW_STREAM_NOT_SUPPORTED
(HRESULT)0xC0AA060D
The provided audio stream is not valid.

So, please can any buddy help me to write very large wav file to Audio CD

Comment: So why do you need to read the entire file into memory in order to write it?

Comment: It's required by IMAPI2 API to read the entire file into memory
IStream stream = mediaFile.GetTrackIStream();
trackAtOnce.AddAudioTrack(stream);
If you have any suggestion, please provide i can test them

Comment: Must be another way, That would mean to write one file onto a dvd you'd use up 4 gig of ram just for the data...

Comment: yes, i am also writing DVD and it has no issue, here i am creating IStream with this methos
Win32.SHCreateStreamOnFile(filePath, Win32.STGM_READ | Win32.STGM_SHARE_DENY_WRITE, ref stream);
but after obtaining stream i am passing this stream to 
trackatonce.AddTrack method throws ComException
E_IMAPI_DF2RAW_STREAM_NOT_SUPPORTED (HRESULT)0xC0AA060D